# Complex numbers - Roots of unity - Proof that $G_d=G_n\cap G_m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$G_d=G_n\cap G_m$$
$$n,m \in \mathbb{N}$$ 
$$d=(n,m)$$

I know how to prove that $G_n\cap G_m\subset G_d$ but proving $G_d\subset G_n\cap G_m$ is giving me a hard time.

I know $\exists r,s\in\mathbb{Z}/ d=rm+ns $

Then $z\in G_d \rightarrow z^d=1 \rightarrow z^{rm+ns}=1 \rightarrow z^{rm}z^{ns}=1 \rightarrow (z^m)^r (z^n)^s=1$

But then what? 
Thanks

Note: $G_n$ is the set of all nth roots of unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see that $G_{d} \subset G_{n} \cap G_{m}$ you want to take $z \in G_{d}$ and show that $z^{m} = z^{n} = 1$. Use the fact that $d = (m,n)$ **divides** both $m$ and $n$.

Comment: $\exists k, q$ such that $ m=dk$ and $n=dq$ then $z^d=z^{dk}=(z^d)^k=1$
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $x\in G_d\Rightarrow x\in G_n\wedge x\in G_m$. To do this, take an $x\in G_d$. You know that $x^d =1$. Now since you know that $n=k\cdot d$ for some $k$, you have

$x^n=x^{kd}=\left(x^d\right)^k=1^k=1$, meaning that $x\in G_n$. Same for $m$.